# Set the ID of View and TextView in titanium appacelerator

Tags: javascript, textarea, appcelerator

I'm creating an for to create randomly textAreas but I need to know which textArea was pressed by the user.

Is there any way to enter a unique ID for each textArea?

How I create the textView:

```
var txtArea = Ti.UI.createTextArea({
  color : '#000',
  backgroundColor : 'transparent',
  font: {
    fontSize : 28,
    fontWeight : 'normal',
  },
  editable : false,
  textAlign : 'left',
  value : a[i],
  textAlign : 'center',
  top : '30%',
  width : '100%',
  height : '100%'
});
```

I tried to put "id : i", but all textAreas returned the same ID.

Comment: how do you get the ID in the event listener?

Comment: Like this: "Var Id = txtArea.getId();"  in the eventListner

Comment: First, TextArea doesn't have getID method. Second, I think you should get the TextArea object from the event object. Otherwise how do you know which one the user clicks? Perhaps share a more complete code. Then we can find out what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not suggested to add custom properties to Titanium proxies. Here is what I would do (based on my guess of what you try to achieve):

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    var txtArea = Ti.UI.createTextArea({
        value : "test n " + i,
        textAlign : 'left',
        textAlign : 'center',
        top : '30%',
        width : '100%',
        height : '100%'
    });
    (function(){
        var id = i;
        txtArea.addEventListener('click',function(){
            console.log(id);
        });
    })();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want assign a numerical ID, you are in the right way but I think that you must insert all TextAreas in rows of Table view. This because you get ID from table view row not from Textarea. Your *id's attemp* was correct if you inserted in a table view row.

Your code for create textArea is something like this:

```
var txtArea = Ti.UI.createTextArea({
    id: i,
    value : "test n " + i,
    textAlign : 'left',
    textAlign : 'center',
    top : '30%',
    width : '100%',
    height : '100%'
});
```

You can furthermore get the `id` of each row simply add a *click Event Listener*, in particular case:

```
tableViewRowName.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log(e.source.id);
}
```

Let me know if works and not hesitate to contact me.

**FULL EXAMPLE**

*In your controller js*

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow();
var scrollableView = Ti.UI.createScrollView();
var table = Ti.UI.createTableView();
var tableData = [];
for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++){
    var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow();
    var txtArea = Ti.UI.createTextArea({
       id: i,
       value : "test n " + i,
       textAlign : 'left',
       textAlign : 'center',
       top : '30%',
       width : '100%',
       height : '100%'
   });        

   row.add(txtArea);
   tableData.push(row);
}
table.setData(tableData);
scrollableView.add(table);
win.add(scrollableView);
win.open();
```

This is what i mean: in your structure you have already an empty table view.
You populate dinamically this table in your controller, with a loop (for or while it's the same).

Every iteration you push the row with the respective TextArea and at the end of loop you populate the table with `setData`

Regards

Comment: I have put my textAreas inside a ScrollView. Cloud It be the reason for not working?

Comment: Try to put tableview in your scrollview. For get id, you must insert textarea in a tableview... If you have a scrollview is not a problem.

Comment: then it will by like: for(int i = 0; i< array.lenght; i++){ inside the for I add the textArea to the tableView and add the tableView to the scrollView}. Do I need to create a new tableView for each incrementation of mai for variable or do I create the tableView outside my for? And thanks for your answers

Comment: @Manuel_Rodrigues, i have edited my post with a full example. I hope this is more clearer.

Comment: The problem is that I'm not working with alloy in my project

Comment: It's not a problem, i edit my post again. @Manuel_Rodrigues